# Problems accessing multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i'm running a $.getJSON statement and i'm having some problems... here's the json:

```
{
    "K-6608-1-0": [
        {
            "Info": [
                {
                    "SVGFile": "46658.svg",
                    "Name": "Faucet Parts"
                }
            ],
            "Parts": [
                {
                    "Cod":"70012",
                    "Name":"Ruela de Parafuso Reforçado B2",
                    "Price":"$100"
                },
                {
                    "Cod":"71131",
                    "Name":"Parafusasdasdasdsdao Reforçado B2",
                    "Price":"$45"
                },
                {
                    "Cod":"78208",
                    "Name":"Tubo de Conexão R2D2",
                    "Price":"$150"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So, let's say i've made the getJSON that way:

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data){
   alert(data["K-6608-1-0"]["Info"]["SVGFile"]);
})
```

Why this code doesn't return "46658.svg"? Where's the error?

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: `data["K-6608-1-0"]` is an array containing one element which is an object, so is `Info`. You want `data["K-6608-1-0"][0]["Info"][0]["SVGFile"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`K-6608-1-0` and `Info` are arrays, so you have to set the position.

```
alert(data["K-6608-1-0"][0]["Info"][0]["SVGFile"]);
                         ^          ^
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `data["K-6608-1-0"]` is an array, so to access the property you want, first you have to access an element of this array bi its index (`data["K-6608-1-0"][0]["Info"]` is also an array):

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data){
    alert(data["K-6608-1-0"][0]["Info"][0]["SVGFile"]);
    //                       ^          ^
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(data["K-6608-1-0"][0]["Info"]["SVGFile"]);
                        ^^^--- add this
```

you've got arrays nested in objects nested in arrays nested in.... The first K-whatever is actually an array. You'll probably have to do the same for deeper levels as well.

Comment: `Info` is an array as well.

Comment: You forgot a `[0]` after `["Info"]`, since it's an array too